# Python list print

Tags: python, list, printing

I am learning python and need some help with lists and printing of the same.

List would end up looking list this:

```
mylist = ["a", "d", "c", "g", "g", "g", "a", "b", "n", "g", "a", "s", "t", "z", "a"]
```

I've used Counter(i think lol)

```
class item_print(Counter):
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.items())
```

to make it look like this:

```
a:4
b:1
etc
```

Wondering if there is a way to make it look like this:

```
   "a":4      "b":1
   etc        etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter from the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = ["a", "d", "c", "g", "g", "g", "a", "b", "n", "g", "a", "s", "t", "z", "a"]

for key,value in Counter(mylist).items():
    print '{}:{}'.format(key,value)
```

Comment: @Orion1125...you cn thank by upvoting accepting his answer

Answer (score 1):

I assum you want to format it this way:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter
mylist = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'n', 'g', 'a', 's', 't', 'z', 'a']

grp = Counter(mylist) # group the list
s = sorted(grp.items(), key=itemgetter(0)) # sort the list
for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    print '"%s":%i\t' % (s[i][0], s[i][1]),
    if i+1 < len(s):
       print '"%s":%i' % (s[i+1][0], s[i+1][1])
```

The output:

```
"a":4   "b":1
"c":1   "d":1
"g":4   "n":1
"s":1   "t":1
"z":1
```

Comment: Yes. I built up on Jaco's comment and made it how i wanted it just not as pretty with code. 
Thank you for help, will save this for future.